# Parsing Value from XML in selenium web driver

Tags: xml, parsing, dom, selenium

I am Using selenium web driver. consider this is the below code. The value sent through sendkeys should get fetched from XML file. Is it DOM Parser? DO you have have any example or links to help me? Thank you in advance.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("iterationInfo.note")).sendKeys("Test");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Selenium is not a tool for xml parsing**.You have to use the facilities available in the programming language you are using.

Say for example **if you are using java** in writting selenium test cases **you can use either DOM or SAX parser for xml parsing**. You can refer the link given below for xml parsing techniques :

[XML parsing in Java](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/parsing-xml-using-dom-sax-and-stax-parser-in-java.html)

Answer (score 1):

As @arisalexis said you can parse even a xml with selenium driver, but the appropriate mode should be to combine it with a rich document parser tool like Jsoup. You can then get it like this :

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(driver.getPageSource());
        Elements nodes = document.getElementsByTag("tagName");
        for (Element nodeElt : nodes) {

            String cdata = nodeElt.ownText();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is perfectly capable of XML parsing as HTML is a subset of XML. You can use all the regular methods like By.tagName or By.xpath and read the attribute of element collections etc.

Comment: This sounds good, but it sounds like it's actually not accurate based on other SO posts.  Do you have any references to Selenium selecting content out of an XML file sitting on a webserver?